# Codeigniter ci_sessions table storing ip address as 0.0.0.0 why? even when hosted I am getting 0.0.0.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Hello in my codeigniter I have created table as ci_sessions with following fields

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Every field is working fine, except ip address which is storing as 0.0.0.0 for every client. I have edited my config.php as below.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: why you can't use this `$this->input->ip_address();` in insert query ?

Comment: you have set `sess_use_database` to `FALSE` then how you are getting records in db ?

Comment: I am getting values in database but for ip address i am getting 0.0.0.0

Comment: '0.0.0.0' is the fallback value for the Input::ip_address() method when the IP address is deemed invalid (does not match ipv4 or ipv6 criteria). Where are you hosting?

Comment: @luciddreamz any thing I missed ??

Answer (score 0):

With Linode your app is likely behind a proxy. You can either find out your proxy IP and add it to the whitelist in your CodeIgniter config file (bottom of `/application/config/config.php`), or follow the directions on [Linode's Nodebalancer Reference](https://www.linode.com/docs/platform/nodebalancer/nodebalancer-reference-guide#x-forwarded-for-header) for using the Apache `mod_rpaf` module to remap **X_FORWARDED_FOR** to **REMOTE_ADDR**.